# Simpliest way to store array data in a variable including jquery serialize form for ajax post data

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, I just want to know if there is other way to store data including the jquery serialize form in a variable to used in my ajax data! I already tried

```
   var post = $('#formID' ).serializeArray();
   post.push({ name:'request_id', value:2 });
   postData = jQuery.param(post);
```

then

```
  var postData = $('#frmname').serialize() + '&request_id=2';
```

both process above work smooth! but I've notice that if variable handle many array data it look like I'm have a bad coding.

I want something like this

```
 var postData = {
     request_id: 1,
     search: keyword,
     $('#formID' ).serializeArray()   // not work if this include
  }
```

but when I include the serialize form. it doesnt work.

Is there another way to store array data plus serialize form excluding the code above? Your help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Problem because you must provide key in your object.
Add **data** key   :

```
var postData = {
 request_id: 1,
 search: keyword,
 data: $('#formID' ).serializeArray()
};
```

Comment: yeah! I already think of that one. but how to declare in a file, for e.g in "ajax_request.php' Do I need to check for it for e.g  $serialize = $_POST['data'] ??

Comment: it depends how you send your data to server. For example you send 
something like that: $.post("url", {data: $('#formID' ).serializeArray()}); In server side you must get by $_POST["data"]

Comment: problem with that is in server side bro. can't get the inside form data. for e.g $name = $_POST['name']. its empty. Check this https://api.jquery.com/serialize/